# How to transfer files and settings from Windows 7 x64 to Windows 2008 R2?

Tags: windows-7, backup, upgrade, restore, windows-server-2008-r2

If I want to re-install Windows 7 Enterprise 64 bit (or any other edition of Windows 7), I'd typically use "Windows Easy Transfer" utility built in the OS to backup and restore my files and settings.

But in my case, I'm migrating to Windows Server 2008 R2.

If I remember well -having worked on both Windows 2008/2008R2 before- "Windows Easy Transfer" is NOT installed on Windows server, and it doesn't even understand the format of the backup file it generates (".MIG" file).
I can't remember for sure whether this is true, is it? And if it's true, what is the alternative for transferring the files and more importantly program settings to Windows 2008 R2?

Of course I'm aware of the "manual" option and that automatic transfer sure will not transfer everything.

Options??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to trick Windows Easy Transfer into thinking it is running on Windows 7. [I found these steps](http://www.win2008workstation.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=6801#p6801):

1. Copy `C:\Windows\System32\migwiz` folder from Windows 7 installation to `C:\Windows\System32` on Server 2008 R2.
2. Download [Application Verifier](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=c4a25ab9-649d-4a1b-b4a7-c9d8b095df18&displaylang=en) from Microsoft.
3. Launch (the x64 version of) Application Verifier.
4. Click on *File* > *Add Application*.
5. Navigate to `C:\Windows\System32\migwiz` and add `migwiz.exe`.
6. Expand *Compatibility*.
7. Place a checkmark in the *HighVersionLie* box.
8. Right-click on *HighVersionLie* and choose *Properties*.
9. Input the following values (for Server 2008 R2):

   - Major: 6
   - Minor: 1
   - Build: 7600
   - Product Type: 1
   - Leave rest as 0.
10. Click *OK*.
11. Save and close the program.

Launch Easy Transfer (migwiz.exe).